# Coach versus long distance bus

Tags: language-formation

I would like to know which one is BrE and which is AmE?  The words are coach vs long distance bus.

Comment: In the US, in my experience, a "coach" is simply a bus designed for long distances, generally with a bathroom and more comfortable seats, among other amenities.  Ticketing procedures vary widely, since in some parts of the country you can essentially flag down an inter-city bus and buy your ticket on the spot.

Comment: Dunno how relevant it is anymore, but *bus* comes from *omnibus*, where *omni* means everywhere (as in stopping anywhere, but perhaps also going everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

When I was young the distinction in British English was clear, and defined in the vehicle licencing regulations of the time.

> Bus:  You buy your ticket on the vehicle as you make your journey.
>   Coach:  You buy your ticket in advance.

The length of the journey was immaterial.

Over time this is no longer the case.  The legal changes commenced with the deregulation of public transport by the Thatcher government in the 1980s.

In common usage, a bus is any road vehicle with seating for several passengers.  The legal term is now simply PSV (Public Service Vehicle).
The two largest long distance operators (National Express and Megabus) refer to their vehicles as buses, not coaches.

The term coach is still in common usage to imply either a more up-market experience or a tour (as opposed to a point-to-point journey).

Comment: Fascinating about the difference being a legal term +1. Please could you give your source for that information (and a link if possible)? Thanks.

Comment: I don't ever remember a formal separation enshrined in law, and I have been around in Britain for a very long time! But for me that type of distinction remains. A coach is a single-decker thing with comfy seats (and nowadays toilets) which you take between cities. A bus is either double-decker or single-decker (and thankfully Boris has got rid of the bendy-busses and reinstated proper London Transport double-decker Routemasters (to modern safety standards with disabled access) which you hop on and hop off.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer for British English.

My own personal impression is that, over the years, the word coach is becoming less common and being replaced by bus. This appears to be confirmed by the following graph.

[image]

However, the chief distinction for me is that a long distance bus is usually part of a regular service between cities whereas a coach takes people on a tour.

**Examples**

*Every year I take the long-distance bus from London to Edinburgh to visit my parents.*

*I booked a coach trip around Europe for my wife and me. We stopped over in many of the major cities.*

Comment: I certainly wouldn't take a *bus* from London to Edinburgh - far too uncomfortable. I'd take a coach. These Google things are rubbish. Who audits them?

Comment: @ws2 - They are drawn from corpora based on published works. Many, if not most, of these works, having been published, have also been proof-read and edited. In my opinion this makes them better than mere Google searches.  There have been criticisms that the OCR isn't always accurate especially when reading older printed books but in general they are pretty good. You can find more details here ---> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Ngram_Viewer

Comment: @WS2 - I refer you to a 'coach' company that uses the word 'bus' to refer to its regular timetabled services. https://www.stagecoachbus.com/default.aspx

Comment: In one posting, where there seemed an obvious discrepancy, someone mentioned that they use American publications of British books - which seemed to defeat the object. We are only dealing with Google here. They have no reputation as linguistics scholars. (Things like *Harry Potter* are published in American as they seem to have no confidence that their children will understand that colour = color.)

Comment: What you say is interesting. I think that maybe this is a topic for elsewhere. We are not supposed to engage in discussions via comments. I'll make a final point, I searched Google Books and found this, '*Harry, who knew Diagon Alley very well by now. ... Then there were cats of every **colour***' - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=harry+potter+colour&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1 - So clearly American spellings aren't ubiquitous.

Comment: No, the ones published here are in the Queen's English. But it is my understanding that for the American market they do an entirely separate publication with everything translated into American. That is the case with many books, I am led to believe. And I am not clear that Google really know what they are doing when they compile these charts.

Comment: I suggest we move to chat. Google uses separate corpora for American and British English. A straightforward search combines those corpora. However you are at liberty to specify a specific corpus if you so wish.  I'm not sure this discussion is productive unless you give evidence for your 'understanding'. Note: I don't claim that ngram is perfect - There is no perfect source. However I often use it because it is better (in my opinion) than simply saying 'I think', or worse still, claiming that a personal impression is a fact.

Comment: Google also think I want to go to Vienna on holiday as I keep getting adverts for hotels on line - something I may have said in gmail , perhaps. it's all governed by algorithms - and I aint got much faith in algorithms.

Comment: Every site on the internet including this one is run by algorithms ;-)